# display weather condtion for events location in php

Tags: javascript, php, openweathermap

I have developed an event registration website in PHP. When users view the event, I have to show the weather condition of that location. I've got the code from

https://openweathermap.org/widgets-constructor

And Code is here:

```
<div id="openweathermap-widget-14"></div>

<script>
window.myWidgetParam ? window.myWidgetParam : window.myWidgetParam = [];
window.myWidgetParam.push({
    id: 14,
    cityid: '1254589',
    appid: '<appId>', // Anonymised appId
    units: 'metric',
    containerid: 'openweathermap-widget-14',
});
(function () {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.async = true;
    script.charset = "utf-8";
    script.src = "//openweathermap.org/themes/openweathermap/assets/vendor/owm/js/weather-widget-generator.js";
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(script, s);
})();
</script>
```

But I want know how to pass city id dynamically

Comment: Hello. Welcome to StackOverflow. In the interest of preventing misuse, please refrain from posting your `appId` and other application secrets in your questions as this can lead to misuse. I have edited your appId out of the question for you on this question.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the list of cities you want to support beforehand, you can use the list called `city.list.json.gz` listed [Here](http://bulk.openweathermap.org/sample/) to create a map of selected cities which you can use to dynamically look up the `cityId` and replace that parameter in the snippet you have shared

```js
var cityMap = {
  "mumbai": {
    id: 1275339,
    displayName: 'Mumbai'
  },
  "bangalore": {
    id: 1277333,
    displayName: 'Bangalore'
  }
}

function loadWeather(containerId, city) {
  var cityId = cityMap[city].id;
  window.myWidgetParam = [];
  window.myWidgetParam.push({
    id: 14,
    cityid: cityId,
    appid: '<appId>', // Anonymised app Id
    units: 'metric',
    containerid: containerId,
  });
  (function() {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.async = true;
    script.charset = "utf-8";
    script.src = "//openweathermap.org/themes/openweathermap/assets/vendor/owm/js/weather-widget-generator.js";
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(script, s);
  })();
}


function handleButtonClick(e) {
  var city = e.target.dataset.city || 'bangalore';
  loadWeather("openweathermap-widget-14", city);
}

Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('selector')).forEach(function(el){
  el.addEventListener('click', handleButtonClick);
});
```

```html
<button class="selector" data-city="bangalore">Bangalore</button>
<button class="selector" data-city="mumbai">Mumbai</button>

<div id="openweathermap-widget-14"></div>
```